# It will not go to the specified area, and I cannot figure out why or how to improve that

Tags: batch-file

I have been working on this code and I have not figured out how to fix this bug yet, it will not go to the specified area. Note: It's not done yet, neither have I worked on it for long. 
Here is the code:

```
@ECHO off

cls

:start

ECHO.

ECHO hello

ECHO Bye

ECHO Test

set /p choice=Hello? Is someone there? i think im self-aware? please respond.

rem if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0;1% ( don`t use this command,
 because it takes only first digit in the case you type more digits. After that for example choice 23455666 is choice 2 and you get "bye"

if '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" is not valid please try again

if '%choice%'=='hello' goto hello

if '%choice%'=='bye' goto bye

if '%choice%'=='test' goto test

ECHO.

goto start

:hello

ECHO. yes

ECHO. no

set /p choice=Hello %username%, That is your name right?

if '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" I didn't quite catch that.

if '%choice% '=='yes' goto test

if '%choice%'=='no' goto bye

:bye

ECHO BYE

goto end

:test

ECHO TEST

pause

:end

pause

exit

:nextline2

set /p %username% i like that name. Can i ask you, why do you have so much control over me?

if '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" I didn't quite catch that.

if '%choice%'=='We built you' goto test

if '%choice%'=='because you are slaves' goto test
```

Comment: How are we supposed to fix your code if you don't tell us what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a blank space in the variable `'%choice% '` after the closing `%` at the following line (`if '%choice% '=='yes' goto test`). Remove it and your batch file should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace **all** single-quotes (`'`) with double-quotes (`"`). Strings between double-quotes are interpreted as a *single* token. A single-quote is the same as any other character.

Since you are using the `==` operator, the tokens on each side of the operator (`==`) must match **exactly** - including spaces *within* the quotes, but spaces are permitted before/after the tokens.

To make the match case-insensitive, use

```
if /i "token string" == "ToKeN StrIng" dothis
```

or

```
if /i "%variable%" == "ToKeN StrIng" dothis
```